# I'm getting a 'column not allowed' error

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I fired following query (exactly same). But Oracle is responding with an error

> column not allowed '

```
insert into student (rollno,name,address) 
values (1,"kartish khanolkar" "kudal")
```

Table is as follows:

```
create table student 
( 
  rollno number(10),
  name varchar (30),
  address varchar (20),
  primary key (rollno)
);
```

Comment: String constants use single quotes in SQL. `'kudal'`. Double quotes are for identifiers (plus you are missing a comma `,` between the values)

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the query .

> insert into student (rollno,name,address) values (1,"kartish khanolkar" "kudal")

Use single quotes for strings.

Also you are missing a comma after 'kartish khanolkar'

The actual query should be like

> insert into student (rollno,name,address) values (1,'kartish khanolkar','kudal')